# Selecting all photos in photo booth with a single gesture

Tags: ipad, multi-touch

Is there a way to select all the photos in the iPad 2's photo booth application and copy them to a new/existing album? currently I need to select each photo individually by clicking (touching) it. 
Am I missing some kind of gesture that will allow me to select all of the existing photos in photo booth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: (Originally I had described a way to select multiple photos via the "Photos" app, and I didn't realize you could do that directly within Photo Booth.)

In short, no, you're not missing a secret gesture -- that's currently the only way to do it.

And unfortunately, I do not believe there is a way to create a new photo album on the iPad itself -- you'll have to do that on your computer and sync with iTunes to see the changes.

Comment: do I have to use the "Copy" photos in the photo booth app in order for them to sync with iTunes?

Comment: @Asher No, the "Copy" command doesn't really help you there.  If you're looking for help with photo syncing, try creating a new question.  That will help people in the future who are searching for the answer to your same question.  :]